# Collector App Domain Symbology

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I am currently developing an inspection map using AGOL/ArcMap and the Collector app. I have a series of potential deficiency sites i.e. upgradient, downgradient, lateral, etc... all possible at the same area. In my map I have domains setup for the user to pick a site location (as described above)… is there a way for me to link the domain with a symbol/color? i.e. the user picks "upgradient" and the symbol automatically turns to a red circle, or if the user picks "downgradient" it turns to a green circle.

As of now the only way I can figure to do this is after exporting the data into ArcMap and adjusting the symbology on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In the web map you pick the field you want to style your layer. In this case it would be this field with the coded domain and use the Types style: Learn how to style layer in the Map Viewer and this doc can help you further https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/style-categories.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1084DA17FD3C470B87A004AB55132D38

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should've been able to figure that out as it is the same in the desktop version... however, I am having another issue I'm hoping you might have a suggestion for. 

When I change the symbology based on the coded domains and try to test it in the app they all show up as red boxes when they should be various colored circles. have you any experience with this?

Comment: Are the red boxes the original symbols used?

Comment: Nope, the original symbol used was just a circle. It seems like AGOL just isn't differentiating the symbology and has just picked a random symbol for all.

Comment: Can you share the webmap and layer?